# Como esconder o título do input quando preenchido no formulário usando CSS

Tags: html, css, css3

```
<div class="content">
   <span class="title" for="input_example">Título do campo</span>
   <div class="form-content">
       <input type="text" id="input_example" name="input_example">
   </div>
</div>
```

Existe alguma maneira de fazer no **CSS** com que o `.title {}` fique como `display:none`, se o input de texto tiver com o valor preenchido?

Eu tentei, mas só consegui fazer quando a `div` fica depois do input, gostaria de fazer isso com ele da forma como está, é possível?

[Fiddle Exemplo invertido](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/q7h3ygj8/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente, você consegue fazer isso com o recurso Flex Box do CSS, dando um

> flex-direction: column-reverse;

HTML

```html
<div class="container column-reverse">
   <input type="text" placeholder="teste" class="item">
   <div class="item">
     título
   </div>    
</div>
```

```css
 input[type="text"] ~ div {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column-reverse;
            }

            input[type="text"]:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ div {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            
.column-reverse {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
.container {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.item {
    /* O flex: 1; é necessário para que cada item se expanda ocupando o tamanho máximo do container. */
    flex: 1;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```
https://codepen.io/lucasbpereira/pen/rNjdqzX
```

Comment: Lucas, pode explicar o que foi feito? só colocar o css pode não ajudar quem precisa entender como resolver :)

Comment: Lucas ele conseguiu fazer dessa forma, "mas só consegui fazer quando a `div` fica depois do input". Ele quer fazer com a `div` ou `span` em cima do `input`.

Comment: Cara, valeu, excelente resposta. Mas foi exatamente essa alternativa que acabei chegando sozinho, mas muito obrigado! Também daria usando position absolute, mas eu estava querendo algo melhor, e essa foi a melhor saída.